# change log for Apache Fuseki?

Tags: sparql, fuseki

I was wondering if someone could point me to something like a "change log" for Apache Fuseki.

I've been way behind and I'm upgrading from 2.3.1 to 4.3.1.

Understandably, I'm noticing behavior changes in my existing SPARQL queries. (Aka some queries are no longer working after upgrading to 4.3.1 and some are returning data in a new format).

[Fuseki documentation currently states](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/fuseki2/): "Fuseki provides the SPARQL 1.1 protocols for query and update as well as the SPARQL Graph Store protocol."

So, I'm wondering what version of the SPARQL query and Graph Store protocols version 2.3.1 of Fuseki was using and how I could read about substantive changes.

Many thanks for any advice :)

Comment: 2.3.1 to 4.3.1 is a huge jump (6 years). SPARQL 1.1 was further back (2013) so the versions of SPARQL are the same. "new format" is at a guess, a change in default content negotiation (XML has become JSON?). The formats supported haven't changed IIRC. Query change are possibly bug fixes in the 6 years between versions.

Comment: @AndyS Gotcha. I know it's a huge jump. It's my fault. I'm just way behind. Thanks for all your quick responses (and work on Fuseki in general). I'm learning a lot and I've actually mostly succeeded! My 4.3.1 version is now in production  (and I also resolved a lot of the space issues I was commenting about earlier. e.g. I get the compact function to work). Thanks so much for your help.